# Como guardar en variables campos de un csv en c# y borrar la primera linea?

Tags: c#

En mi código le paso un número de lineas que quiero que coja del *csv* y luego, 
 que para cada línea vaya iterando los elementos que componen el *csv* pero no lo estoy consiguiendo, os pongo el código

**prueba.csv**

```
gato,casa,http,antonio;
perro,abanico,https,libro;
```

**C#**
   class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        int contador = 0;
        int num_lineas;
        string[] array = null;


        var ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        ruta += "/articulo.csv";



        num_lineas = File.ReadAllLines(ruta).Length;



        array = File.ReadAllText(ruta).Split(';');

        while (contador < num_lineas)
        {


            while (true)
            {

                var a = array[contador].Split(',')[0];
                var b = array[contador].Split(',')[1];
                var c = array[contador].Split(',')[2];
                var d = array[contador].Split(',')[3];
                var e = array[contador].Split(',')[4];
                var f = array[contador].Split(',')[5];
                var g = array[contador].Split(',')[6];
                var h = array[contador].Split(',')[7];
                var i = array[contador].Split(',')[8];

                var imagen = array[contador].Split(',')[9];



                Console.WriteLine(c);



                Thread.Sleep(6000);
                break;

            }

            File.Replace(array[contador]); //aqui tengo que borrar la linea que esta dentro del archivo csv


            contador++;

        }





        Thread.Sleep(6000);


    }
}
```

}

lo he modificado así quiero ahora borrar la primera linea del csv alguna idea....

Comment: No debes bajo ningun concepto cambiar tu pregunta original porque entonces las respuestas que te dieron quedan invalidas. Si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela. Fijate que con lo que hiciste, mi respuesta ya no sirve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra solución podría ser usar Linq para leer todas las líneas y a su vez ingresarlas a una lista de una clase definida (para una mejor manipulación de objetos) en lugar de un `array`. Por ejemplo, teniendo la siguiente clase:

```
public class Lista
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string g { get; set; }
    public string h { get; set; }
    public string i { get; set; }
    public string imagen { get; set; }
}
```

Al usar Linq, podrás leer el archivo, omitir la primer línea y a su vez, evaluar que el contenido del archivo contenga las posiciones y una longitud adecuada.

```
var ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/articulo.csv";

var lista = (from p in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("").Skip(1)
                  // El método .Skip(1) omite la primer línea que sería el encabezado
              let parts = p.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              where parts.Length == 10
              select new Lista
              {
                  a = parts[0].ToString(),
                  b = parts[1].ToString(),
                  c = parts[2].ToString(),
                  d = parts[3].ToString(),
                  e = parts[4].ToString(),
                  f = parts[5].ToString(),
                  g = parts[6].ToString(),
                  h = parts[7].ToString(),
                  i = parts[8].ToString(),
                  imagen = parts[9].ToString(),
              });
```

Comment: Edito totalmente su pregunta, y mi respuesta quedo totalmente invalida. Se lo voy a recalcar, tu respuesta es correcta a su NUEVA pregunta. pero se la voy a editar y volver para atras. No borres tu respuesta, Esperemos que haga su nueva pregunta y se la agregamos ahi...